# How does "off" change the meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I read this sentence in a story:"She leaned over to pick Bella's teddy bear off the floor."
I would like to ask if I change "off the floor" to " from the floor" would there be any change in the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: "from the floor" sounds a bit formal, "up from the floor" sounds better to me

Comment: There would be no change in meaning.

Comment: @learner Your model sentence could also idiomatically insert **up** after **pick**. We usually pick things up, whether **from the floor** or **off the floor**.  **Pick it up** is an established expression, when referring to an object lying on the floor/ground. When it comes to fruit, we simply **pick it** unless we are **picking it up** from/off the ground.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no change in meaning.

Different prepositions are appropriate to different contexts. As a very general rule, we would say we took something "off" a *surface* (that is, if one thing is *on top of* the other), and "from" *within* something else.

For example:

- I took my hat *from the wardrobe*.
- I took my hat *off my head*.

It would sound strange if you said "I took my hat *off* the wardrobe" if it was *inside* and not *on top* of it.

However, some things could be regarded as a surface *and* a location - the 'floor' being one example - so it doesn't really matter if you use 'off' or 'from' in this case.